# Regular expression - need to get string from html comment

Tags: php, regex

I need to get string from comment in HTML file, I was trying to do it with DOM, but I didn't find good solution with this method.

So I want to try it with regular expressions, but I can't find satisfactory solution. Please, can you help me?

This is what I need:

```
<!--adress-"String here I need to get"-->
```

Thanks in advance for answer

Comment: HTML isn't a regular language. It cannot be correctly parsed with regular expressions.

Comment: Take a look here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: This may help http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: @Mark: you shouldn't parse HTML with a Regex. However, the argumentation that HTML is not a regular language is usually bogus (since regular expressions are rarely regular, in any existing implementation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into $matches after this code

```
preg_match('~<!--adress-"(.*?)"-->~msi', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Does anybody care to explain his/her downvote so I can improve my answer?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, but it's probably a knee-jerk reaction to your writing a regular expression to "parse HTML". I think it's just wrong of him or her, though, because I don't see why a regular expression can not be used to extract HTML comments.

Comment: One thing: Not all [HTML comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4) are matched by your regexp. Comments are delimited by `--` within the markup declaration open delimiter (`<!`) and the markup declaration close delimiter (`>`).

Comment: @DanielTrebbien: I just followed OP's needs

Comment: @DanielTrebbien according the the specs, `<!--` starts a comment while `-->` ends it, so I fail to see what's wrong with that answer?

Comment: @RikudoSennin: White space is not permitted between the markup declaration open delimiter and the comment open delimiter, but it is permitted between the comment close delimiter and the markup declaration close delimiter. Valid comment: `<!--adress-"String here"-- >`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, not needed. REGEX cannot correctly parse HTML/XML, because it can never be made to take every possible aspect into account, but you can compromise on a stricter syntax in favor of shorter REGEX. The OP has stated his syntax, that expression is valid.

Answer (score 1):

HTML comments are regular; you can just match `<!--adress-"([^">]+)"-->` and get the first group.

This assumes that the comments are always well-formed and always have a quoted string containing no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It will be more accurate:

```
$regex = '<!--(.+?)-"{0,1}(.+?)"{0,1}-->';
preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches_array);
```

Just do the `var_dump($matches_array)` and see results.